# Flutter widget did not swap its location properly

Tags: flutter, dart, swap, flags, country

I am newbie to flutter and trying to swap the location of two flutter widget. I have two dialog content widgets in a row (left and right) which use to show a list of countries in order to select one to display the flag. I need to swap both widgets its location (left one to right and the right one to left) when I click a button and vice versa. here is my condition

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: isSwaped
              ? _pickCountry(toCallBackFunction, 0)
              : _pickCountry(frmCallBackFunction, 1),
          flex: 1,
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: isSwaped
              ? _pickCountry(frmCallBackFunction, 1)
              : _pickCountry(toCallBackFunction, 0),
          flex: 1,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

and here is pickCountry method

```
Widget _pickCountry(Function callBack, int countryIndex) {
return CountryPicker(
  callBackFunction: callBack,
  headerText: 'Select Country',
  // headerBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  headerTextColor: Colors.white,
  countryIndex: countryIndex,
); }
```

I can notice that somehow widget is swapping, even callbackfuntion also swapping, however, the displayed flag is not swapping, it froze.
Can anyone tell me the reason for that and a solution as well?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code of `callBack` you passed to `_pickCountry` method?

Comment: void frmCallBackFunction(
      String name, String dialcode, String flag, String currencycode) {
    setState(() {
     
      isFromDDMchanged = true;
      fromCurrency = currencycode;
     
    });
    evaluate();
  }